# Suggestions for a tool to measure TCP performance of a server

Tags: java, server, performance-analysis, profiling

I have several servers that host a java application. Now I have a requirement to measure the TCP connection performance of these servers. The perf tool have functionalities for TCP profiling but that need the server kernel version to be 4.14+. Are there any other reliable tools that I can use? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are your requirements regarding the server kernel version?

Comment: Any version between 3 to 4